# Is it possible to have error description directly in code?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm when I hover the mouse pointer over a warning/error bar on the right of the window the following preview is shown.

[image: this is the hover effect]
I would like to always have errors shown like this in the main editor. Is it possible?

Comment: Nope. That "preview" is called [Lens mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/lens-mode.html). In Editor ... IDE should be highlighting problematic places with different background or underwaves (this depends on the color schema you are using; using Default one will use "dirty yellow" background for Warnings and red underwave for Errors).

Comment: I can live with that... but I hope that some plugin or future release can add this feature.

Comment: Maybe with some plugin. It's unlikely to appear as standard feature -- lots of people disable even much smaller markers/helpers (e.g. VCS modified/added lines in gutter; light bulb; styling for misspelt words etc) because they are distracting them from reading or writing the code. This is especially important in files that IDE does not understands completely (e.g. new template language or syntax; clever code calls in framework that IDE cannot figure out..) where you may see whole scrollbar full of yellow warn markers - imagine how such code will look with such detailed messages in actual code

Comment: In fact it would have to be toggleable with a key combination, to prevent that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to always have errors shown like this in the main editor. Is it possible?

Nope.

That "preview" is called [Lens mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/lens-mode.html).

In Editor ... IDE should be highlighting problematic places with different background or underwaves (this depends on the color schema you are using; using Default one will use "dirty yellow" background for Warnings and red underwave for Errors).